# Is there a way to link the methods in my script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I previously had all of my code inside the `Update()` method but I decided to split everything up into different methods to make my code look cleaner but now I get the error: `The name '' does not exist in the current context` for many different variables. I understand the error but I'm just wondering if I am missing something here.

For my CharacterController I use `Vector3 move` as my input and to handle my movement, but when I want to use `move` in another method, I get the error above. The way I solve this is by creating another, new `Vector3 move` inside the particular method.

When I delete all of my methods and place all my code together in the `Update()` method, the error goes away. I thought I solved the problem by having all my methods called together inside `Update()` like below, but that didn't change much.

```
// Snippet
void Update()
{
    HandleMyInput();
    HandleDashForward();
}

void HandleMyInput();
{
    x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = transform.forward * z + transform.right * x;
    velocity.y += -9.81f * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}

void HandleDashForward()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.H))
    {
        move += new Vector3(...);
    }    
}
```

I took some code out just so I could show the issue only.

Comment: Variables have "scopes", it means which part of your code can "see" your variables. see: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/variable-scopes-in-csharp

Answer (score 0):

You need create property 'move' outside method HandleMyInput (for example as private class property), or return from one method and use in another:

```
void Update()
{
   var move = HandleMyInput();
   HandleDashForward(move);
}

Vector3 HandleMyInput();
{
   x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
   z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

   Vector3 move = transform.forward * z + transform.right * x;
   velocity.y += -9.81f * Time.deltaTime;
   controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
   return move;
}

void HandleDashForward(Vector3 move)
{
   if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.H))
   {
       move += new Vector3();
   }    
}
```